# Rails gems installed but the rake task is still giving an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rake, rake-task

I have Rails 3.1.3 installed on my machine with Rake 0.9.2 . When I do `gem list`, I see both installed with the correct version but when I run `rake db:migrate` I get the error saying

> Missing the Rails 3.1.3 gem. Please `gem install -v=3.1.3 rails`,
>   update your RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environment.rb for the
>   Rails version you do have installed, or comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION
>   to use the latest version installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using bundler? If so, try using `bundler exec rake db:migrate`.